# Enable date every Thursday but disable certain Thursday

Tags: wordpress, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to ask about datepicker. I am currently developing a website where university students have to pick their own Thursday to hear a talk about career.

First of all, I have managed to disable all days except Thursday. The code I wrote stated below :

```
<script>
  $( function() 
{
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate: 0, maxDate: 
'2018-12-15', beforeShowDay: function(date){var day = date.getDay();return 
[day == 4,'disable'];
}});
  } );
</script>
```

But now I would to disable a certain Thursday for example next Thursday which is:
'yy-mm-dd' = '2017-08-17'

Can someone explain to me how or where should I do the modification to the code which can allow me to disable a certain Thursday?

**Refer this image for my datepicker** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByJlnNeKIynkQ3IzRTN2cHg4WFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

[`Date.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns a value in the range `0-6`, not `1-7`.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return [date.getDay() === 0,''];
}
```

Comment: I need to add where? Before/After my coding?

Answer (score 1):

you can still use the onBeforeShowDay, since it will get called before the datepicker is displayed, because changing months will make the datepicker to render again.

You can use an array that stores the list of dates and change this based on the result from your ajax call. e.g:

```
//at first only september dates will be disabled.
var array = ["2017-08-10","2017-08-17","2017-08-24"];

 $('input').datepicker({
      onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
       // Perform AJAX call and get the list
       //override the array, and now the october dates will be disabled.
        $.ajax({
           url: ajaxUrl,
           type: "post",
           data: serializedData,
           async: false,
           success: function (data) {
             array = data; //["2017-08-10","2017-08-17","2017-08-24"];
          }
        });  
      },
     beforeShowDay: function (date) {
       var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
       return [array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
     }
   });
```

Comment: I tried delete my code and paste yours instead. But the date didnt popped out :/

Comment: Its complete dynamic piece of code, if you want static then remove this line: array = data; //["2017-08-10","2017-08-17","2017-08-24"];